# Blazor Web WebSocket connect event on initial load

Tags: websocket, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsruntime

i've got a Blazor Web app (latest .net8 template) with RenderMode.InteractiveServer set on both HeadOutlet and Routes. all works well.

as part of initial page load - a WebSocket connection is established which takes a bit of time. during this initial load - some interactive elements on the page seem to be inactive. this is not a problem on its own but a bit confusing from the user UI stand-point. blazor reports these steps:

[image]

it seems it would be a good idea to display some sort of spinner until all of these preparation steps as part of initial runtime load are completed and subsequently hide the spinner when all done and ready. which brings to the point where Blazor app needs to be notified that the WebSocket is established and all other relevant steps are now completed.

is there perhaps a mechanism in place where JS runtime reports status to Blazor app on the status of execution?

or is there a mechanism in place to subscribe to whatever events that might be emitted by JS runtime executing establishment of WebSocket and all other initial load steps?

i am not able to stumble into anything comprehensive on this so far and would be grateful to anyone who would be kind to point me into the right direction. thank you.